# What does the phrase "You're six ways to dead" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know what does the phrase "You're six ways to dead" mean. I've never heard it before and can't find its definition anywhere.

I heard it from [this video clip](http://youtu.be/-3uzXvkxA8o) on the 02:00 sec.
Please, help me to figure this out.
And thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never heard this before, either, but it reminds me of the idiomatic expression *six ways to Sunday*, which, according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_ways_to_Sunday), means:

> in every way imaginable

When discussing this phrase, [WiseGEEK](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-the-idiom-six-ways-to-sunday-mean.htm) mentions:

> Before becoming the title of a late 1990s mob-related movie staring Deborah Harry, the idiom "six ways to Sunday" was a less commonly used English expression meaning every way possible, thoroughly, or completely. Tracing the roots of such idioms is not always easy, [but] the meaning behind *six ways to* (or *from*) *Sunday* can be deciphered based on logical assumptions.
>
> In terms of the calendar, there are six days after Sunday, or six days before Sunday, depending on the perspective. The phrase points out the inevitability of reaching Sunday, no matter what day serves as starting point.

---

Given that, I'd interpret the remark to mean:

> You're dead – in every way imaginable!

meaning that death will inevitable for that character (unless something is done about the situation).

Comment: thx a lot, you really helped me :)